# Discrete Regression with Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, python, scikit-learn

I'm currently building a neural network(NN) for regression on a dataset that came from a lab experiment, each sample was ran against a sensor 10 times, yielding 39 independent variables having the same dependent variable.

The database is then made of 120 lines coming from 12 samples, repeated 10 times each, and each sample has the same value for the dependent variable.

Given that, I first split the database into two parts having the same proportion of samples.

(Forgive, please, the code below, I didn't know how to better implement it)

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve

train_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=base.columns)
for samp in base.sample.unique():
    samples = random.sample(list(np.arange(1,11)), k=7)
    int1 = base[(base.sample==samp) & (base.sample.isin(samples))]
    train_set = pd.concat([train_set,int1])
train_out_set = train_set['Target']
train_in_set = train_set.drop('Target, axis =1)
```

The test set was just what was left from the original base minus the train. Manually done.

At first, I tried fitting the data into a three-neuron one hidden layer network with the variables having the fewest outliers:

```
nn = MLPRegressor((3), activation= 'logistic', solver = 'sgd',
                  max_iter = 2000, alpha = 0, random_state =9 )
nn.fit(train_in_set.loc[:,few_outliers], train_out_set)
nn.score(test_in_set.loc[:,few_outliers], test_out_set)
```

For which I received and R² of -0.06 for both sets. Given the low score even for the train set, I thought the NN was underfitting, hence I use `validation_curve` for assessing various sizes of the one hidden layer, but this using using all independent variables:

```
nn3 = MLPRegressor((3), activation= 'logistic', solver = 'sgd', 
                   max_iter = 2000, alpha = 0, random_state = 9 )
train_score, val_score = validation_curve(nn3, train_in_set, 
                                          train_out_set,
                                      'hidden_layer_sizes', range(3,26),
                                      cv =3, scoring='r2')
mts = train_score.mean(axis=1)
mvs = val_score.mean(axis=1)
```

For which I got

[image: Graph for mts and mvs]

I tried doing the same last step which the other parameters of the network, namely, the activation function, the random_state and none gave me a minimal satisfactory value(R² of 0.5).

I was wondering if the problem could be with the CV step, since I can't control which of the sample go into which fold and hence causing low R² scores or am I approaching the whole thing from the wrong side ?

P.S.: I thought of maybe using `MLPClassifer`, but the idea of NN was enabling us at the lab to estimate the target variable of new samples sometimes without the need to prior classification.

Answer (score 2):

With discrete regression, I assume you mean that your target variable has integer values, rather than continuous values? In that case, this would be an example of a ordinal regression problem. There are basically 3 ways for dealing with such data

1. treat this as classification loss (not ideal, because you throw away the order information)
2. just do regular regression minimizing MSE between target and prediction. Then, after training the network, round the outputs to the nearest integer.
3. Use a ordinal regression approach. A common and easy to implement one is ordinal regression via extended binary classification for neural networks. There are basically two papers that have neural network code for this that come to mind:

   - Niu, Zhou, Wang, Gao, Hua (2016). Ordinal regression with multiple output cnn for age estimation. http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2016/html/Niu_Ordinal_Regression_With_CVPR_2016_paper.html
   - Cao, Mirjalili, Raschka (2019). Rank-consistent Ordinal Regression for Neural Networks.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07884

Comment: hi, @resnet, not really. By discrete I mean the output can take only a couple of values in a certain range, not all values in the same range. 
Regarding the first suggestion, I thought of trying use the whole NN as a classifier, but the main purpose of fiting a NN itself and using its power would be lost.
About the second, I can round the output the next decimal ( the values fall between 0.48934 and 1.58399), but I don't see that'd help me with new values :(
The third: I'll take a look and let you know !
Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: It would be an ordinal regression problem then. Either approach mentioned in the two papers above would be doing what you had in mind, i.e., predicting values in a range like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but then also regarding the order information -- the problem with regular classifiers is that if 0 is the true label and you predict 1 it would be penalized the same way as predicting 5, although, 5 is much "more wrong" -- that's why you want ordinal regression not classifiers basically

Comment: Hm, I see. But in this case, is the idea of applying ordinal regression meant to assist in the regression ? The values itself are cardinal ones, not ordinal ones.

About the "more wrong" doesn't using error metrics such as MSE for tweaking the weights take it into account?
This hasn't much to do this with score metric used, right ?

Comment: "cardinal ones, not ordinal ones" ==> I am still confused about how your targets look like since all cardinal numbers are ordinal numbers. You can think of ordinal data as an ordered set. And the difference between ordinal regression and linear regression is that you are don't assume some metric distance between elements of that set. E.g., in the papers I linked, they regard aging as ordinal data if that helps. Maybe you could describe your target variable a bit more to ensure we are on the same page here.

Comment: Hm, didn't think of it that way. Thanks! I know see how it might help me out
Here are all the possible values my ouput can take array ([1.5282973 , 0.77149206, 0.49216313, 0.656028  , 0.38686687, 0.76673172, 0.6500768 , 0.85522294, 0.66603059, 0.52263472, 0.91909771, 0.55434284])

Comment: You can basically remap those values to some labels 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 12 and then model it as a ordinal regression problem then. However, you could also model it as a metric regression problem (and then round to the nearest allowed value for making new predictions) -- random forests have the undesirable property that you cannot predict anything outside the training set range, but in that case it might actually be an advantage.

Comment: Hm, I see. My biggest of modeling it as a classification task was exactly the inability to predict anything outside the training set range. But the ordinal might actually help. The modeling is chemical topics related, but I guess output range of values ain't that bad

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sklearn library that you are using? In this case you could use CV with predefined folds if you cant to access the problem in this way.

However, it might also be useful to try other regression techniques besides neural networks, since neural networks usually benefit from large datasets which is not the case here.

Comment: Yes, it's !
How can I predefine this folds ? By building'em and calling within `cross_val_score` ?
Which other predictor would you say that fits here? I thought of maybe using a Random Forest too

Comment: You can define custom fold sets by defining the train and test indices of each fold as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195078/9770581). You can then pass the fold indices to the [sklearn API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) as a list/tuple.

Tree-based models can definitely be a good choice here, random forests might work or depending on the complexity of the data you might also try gradient boosting decision trees like [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Will take a look at the API. Thanks!
As discussed with resnet, my biggest fear about going with forest is thei inability to get anything outside their training range.

Comment: Okay, that is definitely a point that must be considered. If you want your model to extrapolate, tree-based models are not well-suited. However, some kind of custom cross-validation with predefined folds might help.